# Need to add fade in to image om slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I need to add a fade in and fade out annimation to my image on existing code for slide show. The images must fade in /fade out when user click the buttons. Here is my code.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="imageSlider">
```

```
  <button id="prevBTN" onclick="prev()"> <b>Prev</b> </button>

  <button id="nextBTN" onclick="next()"> <b>Next</b> </button>
</div>
```

---

**Javascript:**

```
var images = [
  "HTMLcert.jpg",
  "CSScert.jpg",
  "javaScriptCert.jpg",
  "PHPcert.jpg"
];

var num = 0;

function next() {
  var slider =
    document.getElementById("slider");
  num++;
  if (num >= images.length) {
    num = 0;
  }
  slider.src = images[num];
}

function prev() {
  var slider =
    document.getElementById("slider");
  num--;
  if (num <= 0) {
    num = images.length - 1;
  }
  slider.src = images[num];
}
```

---

how can I add fade in and out to existing java script code .

Comment: hi try using Animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Great idea but that is for css i need the code for javascript to animate i have tried to fade the image with css and it only work on page load not with onclick

Comment: You better use some existing plugins..my suggestion http://bxslider.com/      you can find here a lot more than your expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add and remove a class to the active slider element in your javascript function like this:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
slider.className += " active";
setTimeout(function(){
  slider.classList.remove("active");
}, 100);
```

And then your css will look something like this:

```
.active {
   animation: fade 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

Comment: Code has been tested and works amazingly weel, thank you very much man.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using CSS3 annimation , by creating a custom animation , add a class using this last  then toggle the class while clicking in the buttons .

bellow a working snippet :

```js
var images = [
  "http://ramg1.net/images/3.jpg",
  "https://www.gregbowe.com/assets/img/htmlcert.jpg",
  "http://www.lordlamer.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/php-cert.jpg",
  "http://www.michellekeselgiancola.com/images/certs/uploads/phpcert.jpg"
];

var num = 0;

function next() {
  var slider =
    document.getElementById("slider");
  num++;
  if (num >= images.length) {
    num = 0;
  }
  
  slider.classList.remove("fade");
  slider.src = images[num];
  setTimeout(function(){slider.classList.add("fade");},10);
  //slider.classList.add("fade");
}

function prev() {
  var slider =
    document.getElementById("slider");
  num--;
  if (num <= 0) {
    num = images.length - 1;
  }
  
  slider.classList.remove("fade");
  slider.src = images[num];
  setTimeout(function(){slider.classList.add("fade");},10);
  //slider.classList.add("fade");
}
```

```css
/* create the fade custom annimation wich set 0 to 1 opacity on an element */
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

/* create the class that trigger the annimation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation: fade 2s ease; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    fade 2s ease; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      fade 2s ease; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         fade 2s ease; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

```html
<div id="imageSlider">

  <img id="slider" class="fade" src="http://ramg1.net/images/3.jpg" width="400px" height="80%" />

  <button id="prevBTN" onclick="prev()"> <b>Prev</b> </button>

  <button id="nextBTN" onclick="next()"> <b>Next</b> </button>
</div>
```